# kartik checkbox X is not working inside kartik Tabs X

Tags: checkbox, tabs, widget, yii2

I'm facing issue with using [checkbox](http://demos.krajee.com/checkbox-x) inside [tabx](http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x)(another widget from kartik).
check box is not rendered fully, instead it is showing loading symbol.

Anyone faced this kind of issue? any solution for this pls?

Comment: You should edit with some code